# Android SlidingMenu listeners for secondary menu open events

Tags: android, event-listener, slidingmenu

how to handle secondary menu open events while using SlidingMenu library in left_right mode 
 i found code for OpenListener for BehindContentView menu

```
getSlidingMenu().setOnOpenListener(new OnOpenListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onOpen() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"left menu",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

How i add similar  listener for secondary menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the same..

```
/**
 * Sets the OnOpenListner for secondary menu  {@link OnOpenListener#onOpen() OnOpenListener.onOpen()} will be called when the secondary SlidingMenu is opened
 * 
 * @param listener the new OnOpenListener
 */

public void setSecondaryOnOpenListner(OnOpenListener listener) {
    mSecondaryOpenListner = listener;
}
```

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java#L887